# Visual Studio 2012: Is it possible to find out how much memory is used for an object while the program is executing?

Tags: visual-studio, class, object, memory, memory-management

I have created a class in C++ with many variables, these variables include vectors, vectors of vectors, unordered_maps etc.

The logic of this class is simple, I create an object of the class, I pass a value(integer) to a function and it does all the work to fill the variables with data.

I'm interested in learning whether it's possible to find out the total amount of RAM memory that the object of this class consumes during execution time. This will help me understand whether I should find another way to store the data or leave it as it is.

Thank you in advance